# Create a grid of triplets

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a grid that lists all triplets that sum to 1, discretized at 0.01. Here is what I have tried, without much luck.

## First try

```
import numpy as np

w1 = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
w2 = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
w3 = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)

x, y,z = np.meshgrid(w1, w2, w3)

a = np.meshgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:100j, 0:1:100j]
```

## Another try:

```
grid = []
for i in range(100):
    grid.append([])  # Question: now that I have a list of lists, how to fill this with values?

for entry in grid:
    entry = ???
```

Comment: How would you have a grid of triplets? I mean, which would be your two axis? Would "triplets = {(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 0.01, 0.99), ...}` be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it.

Answer (score 2):

How about taking all possible values of `x` and `y` and then computing what the appropriate value of `z` would be:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

grid = np.array([(x, y, 1.0 - x - y) for (x, y) in
                 itertools.product(np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.01), repeat=2)
                 if x + y <= 1.])
```

This uses [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get the cartesian product of `x` and `y`, although [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) would work just as well.

We can show that the resulting triples sum to 1 (modulo some rounding errors):

```
>>> set(grid.sum(axis=1))
{0.99999999999999989, 1.0}
```

Here's a pure `numpy` version of the same approach; I'm using [`np.mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) instead of `meshgrid` because it gives me back a single array instead of a tuple of two arrays:

```
xy = np.mgrid[0:1.01:0.01, 0:1.01:0.01]
z = 1. - xy.sum(axis=0)
grid2 = np.concatenate([xy[:, z >= 0.],
                        np.atleast_2d(z[z >= 0.])])
```

Here's the same sanity check (`grid2` is transposed with respect to `grid`; that is, their shapes are `(3, 5151)` and `(5151, 3)`, respectively):

```
>>> set(grid2.sum(axis=0))
{1.0}
```

Comment: I works perfectly! Can you show how it would be using meshgrid? I strugled so much on that...

Comment: @EricDuminil good point!  We could just use `repeat=2` on `itertools.product`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate 100**3 times. Here's a plain Python solution without any `if`:

```
[(x, y, 100 - x - y) for x in range(101) for y in range(101 - x)]
```

It outputs:

```
[(0, 0, 100), (0, 1, 99), (0, 2, 98), (0, 3, 97), (0, 4, 96), (0, 5, 95), (0, 6, 94), (0, 7, 93), (0, 8, 92), (0, 9, 91), ..., (95, 1, 4), (95, 2, 3), (95, 3, 2), (95, 4, 1), (95, 5, 0), (96, 0, 4), (96, 1, 3), (96, 2, 2), (96, 3, 1), (96, 4, 0), (97, 0, 3), (97, 1, 2), (97, 2, 1), (97, 3, 0), (98, 0, 2), (98, 1, 1), (98, 2, 0), (99, 0, 1), (99, 1, 0), (100, 0, 0)]
```

You only need to divide by `100.0` and put the triplets into an `np.array`.